# How to get data from other native app content provider in React Native application

Tags: android, react-native

I am not able to figure out how to get data from content provider to react-native. I used RNFS in react native and my Uri is content://path to the content provider.

```
const exFile = await RNFS.exists('content://XXXXXXXXX/user_info');
if(exFile){
    console.log('------------exist--------------'); 
} else {
   console.log('----------not exist------------');
}
```